# Create a view that links to another view

Tags: 7, views

I'm trying to create a view that works as category page (aggregates a list of titles from content pages I've created). I need that list to link out to another view that is used to display photo galleries. Am I approaching this the correct way?

I want it to be dynamic so the customer can create photo galleries and they will automatically populate in the category page; then, a link send you to the proper display view.

Comment: Hi ! - Are you photo galleries content types or taxonomy terms ? When you say "link out to", do you mean simply display a link to the page of the gallery ?

Comment: Hi Gregory. As it is right now- I'm just using content types with a tag (with unlimited image field) to display a certain gallery. I want to be able to have several galleries and seperate them within categories. Should I do this another way?

Comment: I figured out what to do. I created a new field on the content page, used it as the gallery view url. Then used the rewrite token of that field for linking url. The title categories will now go to that view. Thanks for the help. -James

Comment: It's great that you figured it out. You can submit an answer to your own question to help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the name of views are view1 and view2 as content pane.You have to link view2 to view1.

For linking one view to another you would have to follow some simple steps:

1. In view2 you have an option under **PANE SETTINGS** 'Link to view' and select **Yes**.
2. In view1 also you have an option under **PANE SETTINGS** 'Link to view' and select **Yes**.
3. Now decide the place where you want to display view2.
4. Suppose its the footer region. Go to the footer region and add a **Global:View area**.
5. There you have a list of all views. Select view2 and save the view.

This way you can let one view execute under another view.

[image]

Comment: Could you, please, supply a screen shot. I could not able to find `Pane Settings`?!

Comment: @sємsєм, make sure you are creating a custom pane instead of block of the view.

Comment: This option will only be seen if you create a panel pane.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this issue:

Use a tag, on your content page, that has the same url as your gallery view has. Make sure that the order of your fields, in the views config page, has the title field coming after the tag field.....in order for the tokens to appear in the rewrite section of the title field. Add the content:tag token to your title field, as the link url. Now you have a category page that uses titles to link to view galleries. Create view as a block to offer list on other pages.